# How does Chronicle map behave when off heap memory is full?

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, chronicle-map, off-heap

I download some files, and store them off heap using an in-memory chronicle map. I wanted to understand the behaviour of chronicle map, when I exceed the amount of native (off-heap) memory available. I have 2 Questions regarding it:

1. Does the data get spilled to disk? If not, what happens exactly? If we get an error, what are the best ways and practices to avoid such errors?
2. If we don't close chronicle maps once we are done using them (or if we have a memory leak), will it keep on filling up off heap memory? Will it cause JVM failure when the off heap memory is full, or will the OS intervene and clear it up for us?

Answer (score -2):

Versus Hash Maps, Chronicle Maps can use Garbage Collection far more efficiently and has or implements max CM entry size. In terms of Garbage Collection it's much faster than Hash Maps also. I'd suggest having a look at the following. https://dzone.com/articles/java-chroniclemap-part-1-go-off-heap

As for memory leaks, I assumed when it came to Java, the JVM handled memory, as well as avoiding memory leaks.

Comment: "Chronicle Maps can use Garbage Collection". First of call it does not _use_ garbage collection and then you do know garbage collection collects only heap, right?

Comment: it's a new concept for me, maybe this article could offer some more insight
https://www.baeldung.com/java-chronicle-map

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the clarification. I should have known better.